# Node v12: module is not defined when exporting

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I export a function in my index.js

```
module.exports = {
  myFunc
};
```

and I run node index.js I got error of

```
module.exports = {
^

ReferenceError: module is not defined
```

Is there any new way to exports something in node version 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your app is using [es-modules](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_determining_module_system) which means you need to use `export`/`import` instead of `module.exports`/`require`. Here's how you could fix it:

```
const myFunc = () => {
    console.log("test");
}

export {myFunc};
```

You can then `import` the function using:

```
import {myFunc} from './index.js'

myFunc();
```